# custom directive is not getting called in angular js

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-forms

I have a simple custom directive with a http post call to a url. When the submit button is clicked it supposed to call the url as custom directive attribute is placed inside the tag.

I checked in chrome console that its not getting called. I am not sure where I went wrong.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
            app.directive('sendMail', function ($http) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                        $http.post('MailSenderServlet.do').success(function (data) {
                        });
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>
        <title>Registration Form</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-muted">Registration form</h2><br/>
            <div>
                <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <label class="control-label">First name:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm " name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="user.uname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span>
                        <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted && myForm.uname.$error.required">Please fill field above<br></span>
                        <span style="color:red" class="hide-while-in-focus" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.unique">Username already exist<br/></span>
                        <span ng-if="myForm.uname.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" ng-model="submit" send-mail ">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it should call right after directive loads, place a `alert();` inside the link function and remove current items inside the link function and you will see the `alert();` http://plnkr.co/edit/VmknY04jPcJDoigaOXxy?p=preview

Comment: `link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {alert("Hi");}` ?? I tried this, I didn't get any alert

Comment: @kittu: See my answer, you just need a minor tweak..

Answer (score 1):

it should call right after directive loads, place a `alert();` inside the link function and remove current items inside the link function and you will see the `alert();`

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/VmknY04jPcJDoigaOXxy?p=preview)

but if you want to call a function right after the button click, you need `ng-click` directive and a controller function to execute after the click in directive controller or link function.

```
<button  ng-click="sendData()" class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" ng-model="submit" send-mail>Submit</button>
```

`ng-click` directive added.

```
app.directive('sendMail', function($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        //alert();
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.sendData = function() {
          alert('send data here');
        }
      }
    };
});
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/DgMgDIrolzGO7hsn4LQi?p=preview)

Comment: But actually I have ng-click already for other function like this: `<button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="submit($event)">Submit</button>`

Comment: then call that directive function after the `submit($event)` function as `<button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="submit($event); sendData()">Submit</button>`, or the proper way to do this is do the `ajax` in `submit()` function.

Comment: @K.Toress do you really feel that making directive for ajax post.? then why not `ng-submit`?

Comment: absolutely not NO may be he is has some other concerns for it.

Comment: @K.Toress I don't think so as hes code looks very straight forward.

Comment: @kittu are you going to do any thing different that just making ajax post..thats all?

Comment: Only http post call to url. I thought It would be only in directive. I am new to angular

Comment: @K.Toress I modified the directive as you said and included `sendData()` in button tag but still url is not being called

Answer (score 1):

I prefer you shouldn't go for directive if it only contains an ajax call. You can do it just by using `ng-click`/`ng-submit`(which is actually meant for forms.) no need of directive here.

You need to correct below certain thing into your code.

1. We don't need to use `ng-model` for submit button it doesn't make sense as don't contains any value.
2. Also you don't need to add action and method attribute on your form, cause anyway you are making from JavaScript code.
3. While submitting form angular does already provide a directive which is `ng-submit`.use that would make more sense.
4. You need to pass data in your post `$http.post` call.

**Markup**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit(myForm)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm " name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="user.uname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span>
        <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted && myForm.uname.$error.required">Please fill field above<br></span>
        <span style="color:red" class="hide-while-in-focus" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.unique">Username already exist<br/></span>
        <span ng-if="myForm.uname.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" send-mail="">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.submit = function(form){
   if(form.$valid){
       $http.post('MailSenderServlet.do', {user: $scope.user})
       .success(function (data) {
           //
       });
   }
   else
     alert("Please validate your form")
}
```

Comment: Why you are passing ` {user: $scope}` as params in post I didn't understand?

Comment: @kittu that my bad..it should be `$scope.user` sending user data from scope to server

Comment: This is actual code with some other directives and controllers. So Shall I use the above approach you posted. Please have a look the plunker once  http://plnkr.co/edit/O7EYWTwXUUC7tfvJuXf8?p=preview

Comment: I tried pankaj. As the app code is getting bigger its becoming more confusing. Anyway I tried but still didn't work :( Everyday I am learning angular almost whole day to figure only small portion of chapters.

Comment: @kittu Ohh..thats cool..but I;d suggested you to follow this step only..which can make your code readable and maintainable..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81800/discussion-between-kittu-and-pankajparkar).

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is simply the controller part you've written

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

Either add a controller part, or just remove it, code works fine.

**See Demo** : http://jsbin.com/hulujarugu/edit?html,console,output

**JS**:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.directive('sendMail', function($http) {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
             alert(1);

             $http.post('MailSenderServlet.do').success(function(data) {});
         }
     };
 });
```

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-muted">Registration form</h2><br/>
        <div>
            <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label class="control-label">First name:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm " name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="user.uname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span>
                    <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted && myForm.uname.$error.required">Please fill field above<br></span>
                    <span style="color:red" class="hide-while-in-focus" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.unique">Username already exist<br/></span>
                    <span ng-if="myForm.uname.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
                <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" ng-model="submit" send-mail >Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: in MainCtrl I have this `app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.submit = function ($event) {
        if ($scope.myForm.$invalid)
        {
            // Or some other update
            $scope.myForm.$submitted = true;
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
});`